# How to use asset_path with files on Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My understanding is that in production something like the following will produce a path with a hash followed by `foo.img`.

```
<%= asset_path 'foo.img' %>
```

But if I instead put the file `foo.img` not in the Rails app but in the Nginx reverse proxy ( and therefore without any prefix hash), then how am I suppose to refer to the correct path? If `asset_path` will produce a path with a hash prefix then how do I get it to refer to the correct path so that image requests will hit Nginx's `foo.img`?

Am I suppose to precompile for production and copy that to a directory that nginx knows about?

Comment: Your final sentence is exactly what you should do. All assets should be written to a public directory, and Nginx should only need to know about the directory and not about individual files.

Comment: @ssorallen: is there a tutorial that describes this and all the other things I should do for setting up Nginx with Rails?

Comment: The section in the Rails docs about "In Production" for assets has some examples for Nginx configs. The whole section is worth a read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Answer (score 0):

You can set the url path via config.assets.prefix and the place where assets are looked for is configured with config.assets.paths.

From the guide on [configuring assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets):

```
config.assets.paths contains the paths which are used to look for assets. Appending paths to this configuration option will cause those paths to be used in the search for assets.

config.assets.prefix defines the prefix where assets are served from. Defaults to /assets.
```